# White space at the bottom of button?

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling with this piece of code, I can't remove the white space that appears in the button(sometimes is on the top, and sometimes in the bottom) [here is the css code that isnt working](https://jsfiddle.net/mzLro740/)

```css
#filter {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid rgb(37, 101, 135);
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: scale(4) translate(50%, 50%);
}

#filter::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<button id="filter">Filter: Off</button>
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share image of button having white line, sorry but i am unable to see it. or else please remove background color property from your css

Comment: @jualahmed what do you mean with 'remote'? did you mean 'remove'? i did remove it, and nothings seems to be fixed =(

Comment: sorry for mistake i it';s remove. i said remote background-color: transparent; css line

Comment: @jualahmed - You can edit your comment

Comment: @PratikshaKale imgur.com/5S0mYQ3 here is an image

Comment: @G-Cyr Google Chrome: 80.0.3987.106 (Build oficial) (64 bits) (cohort: 80_87_Win)

Comment: strange, mine : Version 80.0.3987.116 (Build officiel) (64 bits) , i do not see any issue

Comment: @G-Cyr it seems to be chrome, I tested it on Firefox 72.0.2 (64-bit) now and it works fine without the line, why? I don't know

Comment: @sodero472 what do you actually want to achieve with the ::after element?

Comment: @YvesVanBroekhoven a background animation

Comment: @sodero472, have you tried removing the transform? Do you see still see the issue?

Comment: @YvesVanBroekhoven the transform is there just to scale the image so you all can see the button without zoom in, it was added after the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is when we zoom a little bit on browser the extra space shown in button, here is a solution that worked for me:

I use `border: thin solid rgb(37, 101, 135);` rather then `border: 1px solid rgb(37, 101, 135);` on `button` id `#filter`

I found this solution across this link: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/r1neUxqo5Gc

Comment: thank you for the welcome, but I'm talking about the white line, idk if you can see it in the fiddle, but here goes an image: https://imgur.com/5S0mYQ3

Comment: @sodero472 i didnt see it in the fiddle but you can try setting `height: 100%;width: 100%;` to `#filter::after`

Comment: @Awais nice find, I indeed see the issue when the window is zoomed in.

Comment: @Awais thank you sm, your code works as it should, i will update chrome anyways